# Is there a word/idiom/proverb for this Hindi phrase?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, translation, proverbs, hindi

I'd like to know if there is anything for this in English which is roughly:

> Shoot many arrows, one will fit.

I am from India and we have an idiom dedicated to it in Hindi but I, literally, searched the whole internet but failed to get anything similar in English. It can meaningfully be said as:

> Try every option available, one will surely succeed.

Do you have any magical idiom/proverb or magic word for it that Google is trying to hide from me?

Comment: Please give the original Hindi as that can help immensely even if there is no direct translation that is common in English.

Comment: I'd say "It's a numbers game" or "If at first you don't succeed, try try again."

Comment: Mitch, actually I searched the same original Hindi text on Google but failed to get anything(in Hindi). It doesn't show there. Anyway, actual text is " sau patthar maro, ek to nishane par lagega". But it meant as I described above!

Comment: The duplicate has: 'I made up a 'saying'  that I think describes what I want to say quite nicely:

_If one shoots enough arrows at the target, one is sure to hit the bull's eye._

An actual English idiom I know of that is close in meaning is:

_Throw enough mud at the wall and some of it will stick_.' // An answer is _Even a blind squirrel finds a few acorns._

Answer (score 1):

> "Even a blind squirrel finds a few acorns."

Meaning: if you try enough times, you'll occasionally get the right result.

A less fitting example is:

> "Even a broken clock is right twice a day."

Meaning: if you take the same approach to enough situations, it will occasionally be the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

> > Try every option available, one will surely succeed.
>
> Do you have any magical idiom/proverb or magic word for it that Google is trying to hide from me?

We often call this taking a *shotgun approach*. For example, "We took a shotgun approach to the problem and eventually found a solution".

The term refers to the way a shotgun fires a large number of small pellets, not particularly accurately, but because of the wide spread of the shot it is very likely to hit a target.